# Check form with onclick() function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my third night working on the same code... can`t get it right after days of google and tutorials and I am so tired of it... I am beeing desperate right now...

On short, I have a form and I use a button `type="button"` to generate a second button `type="submit"`.

Before the second button appears, I need to check all required inputs if empty and after completion, show the second button.

I created a mixed code which now verify if inputs are empty, and highlights them **one by one**, not all inputs empty at the same time as I wanted.

I wanted to show highlighted all empty inputs not one by one and if one input is filled it should remove highlight class.

My work so far can be found here: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNjqEy)
Most important of all, I have a calculator which is calculating from inputs values. This is the reason I am using first button `type="button"`.

How to get this to an end? I am so tired of this. Thank you.

**LE:** Partially fixed it by removing some `return false;` code from function. It has some errors although. For example, if you complete the last three inputs without completing and the ones on top, will submit anyway.

Comment: You should look into [JQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: First of all, for your sanity, you should make a simplified version of the problem, with only two form inputs. There's just too much going on right now that could be causing problems.

Comment: All I must code for verifying inputs, must be inside the function validateForm(). I need the second button to be type="submit" for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `required` attribute. It won't have any effects as you're not submitting the form, but then you could select all required fields with `document.querySelectorAll(":required")` or with jQuery `$(":required")` and loop through all of them validating each one.

Comment: I did something similar in a posted answer of mine, using document.getElementsByClassName, but it does not highlight all empty field, but one by one.

Comment: Maybe because you're interrupting the execution with `return` like in the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false when a value is empty, so it's stopping the function, that's why they highlight one by one.

Comment: Indeed so. I reviewed it and now it works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this basic validation using JS and get idea what to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateMe(){
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        if(name==""){
            //do something
            alert("name can not be null");
            return false;
            //this will not submit your form
        }
        else if(phone==""){
            //do something
            alert("phone can not be null");
            return false;
            //this will not submit your form
        }
        else{
            return true;
            //This will submit your form.
        }
    }
</script>


<form action="somewhere.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateMe();" >
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
    <input type="submit" value="check and submit"  />
</form>
```

NOTE: This is very basic validation using Javascript. What you want is to click one button and if valid then show submit button. But why you want do that if you want only validation. Why two buttons one to check values and show submit button and another button is submit itself. Why?

Comment: The other button when pressed will: store info to database, create pdf based on info and send 2 mails with that pdf.

Comment: then simply make this button as button and call this method, where return true put your button show code, and where return false show your validation msg. By default hide your submit button and after satisfying each condition then show your submit button simply

Comment: For the second button I made just the first side. It is writing the values to database when pressed.

Comment: I am too menthaly tired to understand now what to do exactly. I will re-read you advice in the morning.

Comment: Okay, If i get time i can post full code for you with this short example

Comment: Only if you have the time. If not, leave it please. There are other important things. I am sure I will better understand after some good sleep. Thank you very much Ssingh.

Answer (score 0):

I created another short loop function BUT after inputs are filled, `newButton` button does not show. All Inputs are turning green from empty red. Please see the positioning of the `return false;`

```
function validateForm() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-calc");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].value == "") {
        elements[i].style.borderColor = "red";

    } else {
        elements[i].style.borderColor = "green";
   return false; // IF PUT THIS HERE, ONLY ONE INPUT AT A TIME IS HIGHLIGHTED BUT IN THE END THE newButton WILL POP UP.
    }
    }
     return false; // iF I PUT THIS HERE IT STOPS HERE, NO NEWBUTTON NEXT.
    var newButton = "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Trimite-mi oferta pe mail' class='buton-calc'/>";
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML= "<span style='margin-left: 17%;'>Oferta personalizată a fost generată</span>"+newButton;
//SOME CODES HERE
});
```

What am I missing?